# ¿Cómo cambiar iconos personalizados en un menú lateral? - Ionic

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, ionic

muy buenas a todos, soy nueva en este mundo de ionic y quisiera saber como cambiar el icono de la flechita del menú desplegable, pero que solo fuera uno en especifico no todos, así es como se ve mi menú, hice un circulo donde quiero que este un más, así:

[image]

Este es mi código:

```
    <ion-item routerLink="/home" detail>
      <ion-icon slot="start"  name="log-out-outline" color="medium"> </ion-icon>
      <ion-label>
        Cerrar sesión
      </ion-label>
    </ion-item>

  </ion-menu-toggle>
  <ion-menu-toggle *ngFor="let c of componentes | async">

    <ion-item [routerLink]="c.redirectTo" detail>
      <ion-icon slot="start" [name]="c.icon" color="medium"> </ion-icon>
      <ion-label>
        {{c.name}}
      </ion-label>
    </ion-item>

  </ion-menu-toggle>
</ion-list>
```

Les agradecería mucho su ayuda, gracias c:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es problema del ion-item.
Tienes que agregar detail='false' para quitar la flecha y agregar un nuevo icono al final que seria el de +
Te quedaria de la siguiente manera cada uno de tus items

```
<ion-item routerLink="/home" detail='false'>
      <ion-icon slot="start" name="log-out-outline" color="medium"> </ion-icon>
      <ion-label>
        Cerrar sesión
      </ion-label>
      <ion-icon slot="start" name="add-outline" color="medium"> </ion-icon>
</ion-item>
```